# Perl create folder combination of variable and underscore

Tags: perl, directory

How can I create a folder which is a combination of a variable and underscore ( and other special characters ) on Windows ?

I need to create this folder C:\CD12.0\PROD12.0_NEW so I tried this

```
  use File::Basename;
  use File::Path;
  my $version = "12.0";
  mkpath("C:/CD$version/PROD$version_NEW") or die;
```

Get this error

```
  Global symbol "$version_NEW" requires explicit package name
```

Comment: I can't test on Windows now, but how about this -- evaluate that into a string, then use that string in `mkpath`.  Like `my $path = "C:/CD${version}..."; mkpath($path, ...);`  Or use `sprintf` to create the string, if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use curly braces or the concatenation operator

```
"C:/CD$version/PROD${version}_NEW"

"C:/CD$version/PROD" . $version . "_NEW"
```

Comment: hem, using curly braces create this C:\CD{12.0}\PROD{12.0}_NEW

Comment: @Epligam Then you wrote `"C:/CD{$version}/…"` instead of `"C:/CD${version}/…"`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing implicit concatenation as in `"this$that"`, you can do explicit concatenation, as in `"this".$that`.

So:

```
  mkpath("C:/CD".$version."/PROD".$version."_NEW") or die;
```

Alternatively, use braces:

```
  mkpath("C:/CD${version}PROD${version}_NEW") or die;
```